# Azure DevOps git checkout using powershell

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm trying to do a checkout using git from a powershell script using Azure Pipelines (yaml).

When I run the following during my build, my build hangs..

```
- task: PowerShell@2
    # ------------------------------------------------------
    displayName: Update readme.txt
    # ------------------------------------------------------
    inputs:
      targetType: filePath
      filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\${{ parameters.devOpsArtifactName }}\update-changelog.ps1'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\${{ parameters.devOpsArtifactName }}'
      arguments: '-WorkingDirectory "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)" -Version "$(buildNumber)" -BranchesToPush "develop" -GitRequestedForEmail "$(Build.QueuedById)" -GitRequestedFor "$(Build.QueuedBy)" -UpdateRepo'
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

```
function Checkout([String]$branch, [String]$gitRequestedForEmail, [String]$gitRequestedFor)
{
    Write-Host "Checking out $branch for $gitRequestedFor ($gitRequestedForEmail)."

    git config --global credential.modalPrompt false
    git config --global user.email $gitRequestedForEmail
    git config --global user.name $gitRequestedFor

    git fetch
    git checkout $branch
}
```

**EDIT**
Supressing the modal (as suggested) doesn't work, preferably I want to use SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN to authenticate.

Comment: Not sure, but I suppose you may have a modal dialog prompt from the Git Credential manager. You can suppress this by adding: `git config --global credential.modalPrompt false`

Comment: Optionally disabling all interactive prompts in Git by adding `set GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0`

Comment: Why can't you specify the branch in the YAML or in the parameters when queuing the build?

Comment: Try to put the username & password in the `fetch` command: `git fetch https://username:password@mygithost.com/my/repository`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that tomorrow and see what works.. I need to checkout, update changelog and push to PR source branch and develop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested using this (inline) script and got it working:

```
$url = "$(Build.Repository.Uri)".Replace("https://", "")
$url = "https://$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@$url"

Write-Host "Checking out $branch from $url for $gitRequestedFor ($gitRequestedForEmail)."

git fetch $url
git checkout develop
git log --oneline
```

Comment: Can you please provide your full YAML? I'm struggling with inline scripts

Comment: you can use `powershell:` for inline scripts, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops