# Error running Invoke-RestMethod with $(System.AccessToken) in a build task

Tags: powershell, authentication, azure-devops-server-2020

I'm getting a 401 (presumably) when attempting to access the REST API using the value of `$(System.AccessToken)` as a credential. The pipeline I'm running is on the same ADS 2020 on-prem server as the API URL I'm using.

The error message in the build logs goes like so:

> TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required. - Azure DevOps Server

Inspired by [this technique](https://adamtheautomator.com/tfs-powershell-examples/), here's the code from my PowerShell inline script task:

```
$Params = @{
  ContentType = 'application/json'
  Headers = @{ Authorization = 'Bearer $(System.AccessToken)' }
  Method = 'Get'
  Uri = 'http://host/collection/project/_apis/build/builds/' + $(Build.BuildId) + '?api-version=6.0'
}

$Result = Invoke-RestMethod @Params
```

I also tried this, borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54416794):

```
$Params = @{
  ContentType = 'application/json'
  Method = 'Get'
  Uri = 'http://$(System.AccessToken)@host/collection/project/_apis/build/builds/' + $(Build.BuildId) + '?api-version=6.0'
}

$Result = Invoke-RestMethod @Params
```

I've taken care to turn on the `Allow scripts to access the OAuth token` option, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=azure-devops-2020&tabs=classic#example-powershell-script-access-rest-api).

The strange thing about it is that it worked the first time through (with the first code block above). Now, no matter what I try, I always get the above error.

How can I use the value of `$(System.AccessToken)` in a Build task to access the REST API on the same server?

**--EDIT--**

I've tried the alternate variable syntax as well:

```
$BuildId = $env:BUILD_BUILDID
$Token = $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN

$Params = @{
  ContentType = 'application/json'
  Headers = @{ Authorization = 'Bearer $Token' }
  Method = 'Get'
  Uri = 'http://host/collection/project/_apis/build/builds/' + $BuildId + '?api-version=6.0'
}

$Result = Invoke-RestMethod @Params
```

Comment: two points ... [1] `$(System.AccessToken)` is not valid powershell code. a variable cannot be defined that way. what is it actually doing? ///// [2] `'Bearer $(System.AccessToken)'` is in SINGLE QUOTES. so, even if the weird variable was valid ... it will not be expanded at all. you will only get the exact text shown in the single quotes.

Comment: Actually, in an inline script it is. System/Build/Release variables are available when the script is inline. But nevertheless I get the same result as well when using the `$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` syntax. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up the point about the single quotes. Up 'til now, I'd assumed that they were synonymous with doubles—but some quick testing revealed that they're not. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: inline scripts are NOT powershell _as such_. they are something in another context that presumably _runs_ powershell. you likely otta mention that outer environment in your Question. ///// yes, the difference between the two types of quotes is one that is _quite_ meaningful. [*grin*]

Comment: `you likely otta mention that outer environment in your Question` Ah, but I did! Fourth paragraph ;-)

Comment: oops! [*blush*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much angst, I finally found the combination that works:

```
$BuildId = $env:BUILD_BUILDID
$Token = $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN

$Params = @{
  ContentType = "application/json"
  Method = "Get"
  Uri = "http://host/collection/project/_apis/build/builds/$BuildId"
}

$Result = Invoke-RestMethod @Params -Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer $Token" }
```

I tried it on a whim. I have no idea why this passes when the others don't, but that's OK. It runs. I'm sticking a flag in it.

Comment: it looks like you got rid of the `inline script` stuff. that may well be the "why" of it. [*grin*]

Comment: It's still inline. Here's what the whole thing [looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcZBL.png). Thanks to your single quotes tip, I was able to simplify it quite a bit.

Comment: Ah! i see that you did remove that really odd `$(stuff.here)` syntax. that is what i meant ... sorry for the confusion. [*blush*]

Comment: NP. That's the syntax for [Agent/Build/Release/System variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops-2020&tabs=classic) in Azure DevOps Server. It's pretty extensive.

Comment: thank you for the clarification! [*grin*]